# How can I get websocket instance in a restful handler using vertx?

Tags: websocket, vert.x

I'm new to vert.x. Here is what I want to accomplish:

firstly, I have an endpoint handling client app's restful request.

```
router.post("/clientrequest").handler(routingContext -> {

  // This handler will be called for every request
  HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
  HttpServerRequest request = routingContext.request();

  request.handler(buffer->{
     // This handler will be called for every chunk of my post request with multi-parts
     //

     //client is a HttpClient = vertx.createHttpClient()
     client.websocket("/anotherWebsockReq",ws->{
     //here I get ws as my websocket client instance ws.writeFrame......
        });       
});
```

My question is how can I get a websocket instance to send the remaining buffer without creating a new one in the request. handler loop.

Comment: do I make myself clear?

Answer (score 1):

Get the websocket before handling buffers:

```
router.post("/clientrequest").handler(routingContext -> {

  // This handler will be called for every request
  HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
  HttpServerRequest request = routingContext.request();

  request.pause()

  client.websocket("/anotherWebsockReq",ws->{
    request.handler(buffer->{
      // write your frames here
    }    
    request.resume();
  }

});
```

Note the call to `pause` and `resume`. This is needed because data my lost otherwise.